# get the white coordinates of this image in imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I use command convert picturex.png txt:-

but this command is so slow exist other alternative?

[image]

please help me

Comment: Which set of coordinates do you want to get - the blob in the middle or the rectangle at bottom left? What do you plan to do with them next? What OS are you using?

Comment: the blob ; im trying to calculate the distance with this information ; im using linux ubuntu

Comment: Please try a little harder so folks here can help you better. What distance are you trying to calculate? What is the overall objective? There may be a much better/faster solution if we know what you want to achieve...

Comment: sorry for the confusion
I just need to know where you are the point the distance is not part of the question

Comment: We are still not really getting there... are the dots at the top irrelevant? Can we/you remove them? Is the blob in the middle constrained to move within a specific area? If so, what? Do any of the blobs have a minimum/naximum area? What are you going to do when you the know the white points? Find their centroid? Find their area?

Comment: ok i correct the image

Comment: i need find the coordinates x , y

Comment: for example i see in this tutorial how get the cordinates of stamp http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=30473&p=137733&hilit=stamp#p137733

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
# Find trim box
convert mystery.png -median 3x3 -format %@ info:
13x22+656+353

# Colour it in
convert mystery.png -fill "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)" -draw "rectangle 656,353 669,375" result.png
```

[image]

The trim box is 13 pixels wide by 12 pixels tall and positioned at 656,353 from the top-left corner. The median filter (`-median 3x3`) removes the noisy single-dot pixels.